# Writing(append) a CSV file to a variable using Mule4

Tags: foreach, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have queried a database for records and I have a list of records to be processed. I am performing certain operations on the records using 'ForEach' Iteration. And Inside the 'ForEach' I want to write each record after processing to a CSV file but I don't wanna save that CSV file to a location instead I want to store(append) the contents of the CSV to a variable which I have declared before 'ForEach'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the output of your transformation is stored in a variable.   Assuming the name of the variable is `csv` the code can look as follows:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv header=false
---
vars.csv ++ <expression>
```

Where `<expression>` is replaced with the additional data to be appended.

This is how it can be done using a `Transform Message` processor:

```
<ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" >
  <ee:message >
  </ee:message>
  <ee:variables >
    <ee:set-variable variableName="csv" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
      output application/csv header=false
      ---
      vars.csv ++ <expression>]]>
    </ee:set-variable>
  </ee:variables>
</ee:transform>
```

EDIT:
What I am not certain is whether variables updated/created inside a `For Each` scope persists once its done.

I just tried it with in a flow and it does work--the value persists in the variable outside the `For Each` scope.  Here's the flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd">
    <flow name="amerFlow"
        doc:id="81c2b1b9-f4d0-4938-b517-ac6d5c772f94">
        <scheduler doc:name="Scheduler"
            doc:id="57f150c9-8722-4ff6-915a-dbe8cd61d649">
            <scheduling-strategy>
                <fixed-frequency />
            </scheduling-strategy>
        </scheduler>
        <set-variable value='#[output application/csv --- {name: "Amer", age: 20}]' doc:name="csv" doc:id="d1b80b26-868e-47a5-81c5-57674560b165" variableName="csv"/>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="67e7e8b8-37c4-4720-8c57-555a2b3d5eeb" collection="#[(0 to 5)]">
            <set-payload value='#[output application/csv 
--- 
[
    {name: "Amer", age: 20},
    {name: "Amer", age: 20}
]]' doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="fae2dddb-8823-4bb5-995f-67aad5167297" />
            <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="2dcfcdc7-9bcb-4df3-aaa5-7ebf559d1646" >
                <ee:message >
                </ee:message>
                <ee:variables >
                    <ee:set-variable variableName="csv" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/csv header=false
---
vars.csv ++ payload]]></ee:set-variable>
                </ee:variables>
            </ee:transform>
        </foreach>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="d47afc71-5d16-4044-91d2-1bd2183fcb51" message="#[output application/json --- vars.csv]"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```